# Delete div after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, coffeescript

I have a simple script that should delete a div after the ajax call is success:

```
$ ->
 $('body').on 'click', '.add-comment', (event) ->
   event.preventDefault()
   body = $('#body_comment')
   target = event.target

   $.ajax
    method: 'POST'
    url: '/comments/create'
    data:
     body: body
   success: (data) ->
    target.remove()
   error: (data) ->
    # nothing here
```

If I do:

```
console.log(target)
```

In the success block, it show the correct html div, but nothing happens when I do target.remove() or target.hide()

Where I wrong ?

PS: I've tried also to use $(target).remove() , without success..
new code:

```
 $('body').on 'click', '.add-comment', (event) ->
   event.preventDefault()
   body = $('#body_comment')
   target = event.target

   $.ajax
    method: 'POST'
    url: '/comments/create'
    data:
     body: body
   success: (data) ->
    $(target).remove()
   error: (data) ->
    # nothing here
```

**PPS: OK I've found that was a conflict with another mine script...sorry guys!**

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: @muistooshort I noticed that too, but OP provided his real code gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92020cf606c85b14e843

Comment: @dfsq: (1) That really should be embedded in the question. (2) Notice that there's no `var target` in there? Either that JavaScript didn't come from CoffeeScript or there's still missing code.

Comment: is `->` part of the code? ... or is it shorthand just for representational matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$(target).remove();
```

`event.target` is DOMElement. In order to use jQuery methods, you should convert it to [jQuery instance](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element), but wrapping it into `$` function.

Comment: Tried but not luck :(

Comment: Okay, this is weird. Are you sure the indentation of your code is correct? I can see that `success: (data) ->` should have one more space in front of it. Can you check it?

Comment: your initial point was correct( use $(target) instead of only target.remove()). Then there was also a conflict with a mine script...sorry for the time lost on it! Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad you finally figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Remove is a jquery function so you have to call it like so :

```
$(target).remove();
```

**UPDATE**

event.target is referring to the element clicked inside the .add-comment.

Try this :

```
target = $(this);

success: (data) ->
target.remove()
```

Comment: Your initial answer was correct :) the problem was a mine scripts conflicts...sorry! Thanks.